# How to convert Map<String,List<String>> to Map<String,String>?

Tags: apex, map, convert, variable

I have a Map<String,List> and I want to convert to Map<String,String> converting list to string.join(','). I tried this, but it only replicates one value

```
User u = new User();
List<User> userUpd = new List<User>();
Map<String,List<String>> usersMap = new Map<String,List<String>>();

for(String uMap : usersMap.keySet()){
     u.Order__c = uMap;
     u.Values__c = string.join(usersMap.get(u.Order__c.trim().toLowerCase()),',');
     userUpd.add(u);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you never create a new user in memory, so they all reference each other.

As a basic example:

```
User u = new User();
User u2 = u;
u2.LastName = 'Fear';
System.debug(u.LastName); // Fear
```

You need to create a new user for each iteration through the loop:

```
for(String uMap : usersMap.keySet()){
    User u = new User();
    u.Order__c = uMap;
    u.Values__c = string.join(usersMap.get(u.Order__c.trim().toLowerCase()),',');
    userUpd.add(u);
}
```